# Using a class as the key of a map

Tags: graph, stl, maps, key

I basically want to mark the visited nodes of my graph and i was thinking of using the class as the key directly but it wasn't working.
So, someone suggested that i should use a pair instead; so i have been trying to use that but that's also not working.
My problem is as follows; i am being unable to insert values into the pair-key map i have made .

```
class Node{
public:
    int visited;
    int a, b;
    Node(int x,int y){a=x; b=y;}
}

map<pair <int,Node>,bool >visited;
```

How do i insert values?
What is the best way of marking visited nodes in a graph?

Comment: You need to implement `operator<` for your class for it to work as a map key. Though I can't help but wonder: you have a `visited` member inside `Node` - why do you also need to track it outside?

Comment: oh i put that in as member variable because i was trying to use that technique of marking but i couldn't do it and forgot to remove the variable.

I used a 2d boolean array for the marking and it's working.